# Function returning a session object - is this alright?

Tags: c#, .net, session

Lets say I would like to build an application to connect to a server and upload, delete, ... files.

At first I need to connect somehow and I need a session. Can I build a function that is returning a session and after that I can do whatever I want with this session object? Something like:

```
mySession connect(url, user, password)
{
  //connecting
  return session;
}

void uploadFile(File f) {/*...*/};

var currentSession = connect(/*...*/);

currentSession.uploadFile(...);
currentSession.deletFile(...);
currentSession.close(...);
```

Could this be good? If I have a session object I can pass it everywhere and say `.upload`, `.delete`, `.whatever`.

And what do you think about the functions like `void uploadFile()` - maybe I should change void? Because after an upload how do I know that it was successful? Maybe a boolean is better? (if I get true, I know it was successful and if false It wasnt). Any ideas? ;) Thx

Comment: FYI - [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), [Method Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous experience had the database session wrapped as IDisposable, so consumers would always request the database session via a using:

```
using(var session = Database.CreateSession())
{ 
    session.uploadFile(); 
    session.deleteFile();
}
```

then in the wrapped session's `Dispose` method, it would flush and close the connection and dispose anything necessary.  This way I was ensured (usually) that the connection was closed and disposed of; at least if developers/myself used it properly.

As for your second question, your `uploadFile` can return true/false on success or throw an exception.  If you expect it to fail for legitimate reasons often, perhaps true/false is better.  You could also have it return a `UploadResults` object which has a boolean pass/fail property along with the reason/exception as to why it failed.

```
public class MySession
{
    public UploadResults UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //try upload

            return UploadResults.Succeeded();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return UploadResults.Failed(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class UploadResults
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
    public Exception FailureReason { get; private set; }


    private UploadResults(bool success, Exception failureReason)
    {
        this.Success = success;
        this.FailureReason = failureReason;
    }

    internal static UploadResults Succeeded()
    {
        return new UploadResults(true, null);
    }

    internal static UploadResults Failed(Exception failureReason)
    {
        return new UploadResults(false, failureReason);
    }
}
```

Then your code might look like this:

```
using(var session = Database.CreateSession())
{ 
    var results = session.uploadFile();
    if (results.Success)
        session.deleteFile();
    else
        ReportError(results.FailureReason);
}
```

But that's just one sample; you can play around with the design as it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as passing around your session object goes, I see no reason why you can't so long as it's a reference type(unless there's some qwirk with it that I am unaware of).  But If I were you, I'd try to get an instance running in the debugger, try it out, and then see what happens.

as far as the `void uploadFile()` the implementation is up to you.  From my experience, most `doSomething` functions throw an exception upon failure, so that is what I would do.  Also, if your function fails, there's a possibility that that was because some internal function threw an exception, so I would probably just let that exception bubble up.